# Replace a routine declared in a DB2 module

Tags: sql, module, db2, routines

I am developing an application in DB2 with SQL PL, and the routines (procedures and functions) are being defined in a module.

However, each time I change a routine, I cannot replace it, and I have to drop the module body, and recreated.

Is there any way to do a REPLACE for a routine inside a module?

Comment: So `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE...` doesn't work in a module?

Comment: No, it does not work, because the command is ALTER MODULE XXX ADD PROCEDURE YYYY. I am looking for something like ALTER MODULE XXX REPLACE PROCEDURE YYYY, but it does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to replace a routine (stored procedure or function) in a module, it is not necessary to drop the body and recreate all objects.

In order to replace a routine, it is possible to drop a specific procedure/function, and just recreate it:

```
ALTER MODULE m1 ADD PROCEDURE p1 ()
 BEGIN
  ...
 END@
ALTER MODULE m1 DROP PROCEDURE p1@
ALTER MODULE m1 ADD PROCEDURE p1 ()
 BEGIN
  ...
 END@
```

However, there is not a real REPLACE operation.